# Aesthetic question on function definition

Tags: function-construction, syntax

Consider the standard function `FoldList[].` There are two forms (at least):

```
FoldList[f, x, list]
```

and

```
FoldList[f, list]
```

A function like this can be defined by making two separate definitions:

```
f[a, b, c] := ...

f[a, b] := ...
```

However, is that the approved method, or is there some better mantra?

Comment: You only need the full definition once, the second can call the first: `f[a_, b_] := f[a, First[b], Rest[b]]`

Comment: @SimonWoods So how would that work for the `FoldList[]` example?

Comment: @IgorRivin ... the exact same way? `Clear[foldlist]; foldlist[f_, x_, list_] := FoldList[f, x, list]; foldlist[f_, list_] := foldlist[f, First[list], Rest[list]]`? Could you perhaps clarify your issue?

Comment: @MarcoB Ah, I understand, Simon's answer was specifically for the fold example, and, as you say, it is all fine there. I was looking for a general guideline...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive definition of function that has the same behavior as `FoldList`.

```
f[func_, b_List] := f[func, b[[1]] , b[[2 ;;]]]
f[func_, b_, c_List] := fhelper[func, b, c, {b}]

fhelper[func_, b_, {}, rtn_] := rtn
fhelper[func_, b_, c_, rtn_] :=
  With[{nxt = func[b, c[[1]]]}, fhelper[func, nxt, Rest[c], Join[rtn, {nxt}]]]
```

Tests

```
Clear[g, a, b, c, d, e]
f[g, a, {b, c, d, e}]
```

> `{a, g[a, b], g[g[a, b], c], g[g[g[a, b], c], d], g[g[g[g[a, b], c], d], e]}`

```
f[g, {a, b, c, d, e}]
```

> `{a, g[a, b], g[g[a, b], c], g[g[g[a, b], c], d], g[g[g[g[a, b], c], d], e]}`

Of course, `FoldList` is implemented as an iterator and is more efficient than the above code. However, the above does show the argument patterns for implementing a function like `FoldList`.